# SSH permission denied (password)

Tags: linux, ssh

I am going to connect to another virtual machine with SSH. but I am not able to login (permission denied (password)). maybe I should set password in target system and I do not know how?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in the destination machine `(virtual machine)` which try to access it via `ssh` allow `iptables` to be able to access type :

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: If they're getting a permission denied error, then the TCP part is going through.

Comment: sorry i have added my answer delete `-s` .